# Debug com Flask/Python

Tags: python, flask

Estou estudando o framework Flask. Ocorre que preciso *debugar* um objeto *request* com dados do formulário. Também preciso parar num determinado ponto, tipo o `die()` no PHP.

Como faço isso? Já tentei fazer `os.exit(1)`, mas o servidor do Flask para automaticamente.

Obs: em PHP seria

```
debug(object);  
die();
```

Answer (score 3):

No Flask, para acessar as informações do request é necessário apenas importar o objeto padrão [`request`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#incoming-request-data) que é preenchido automaticamente em todas as requisições da sua aplicação. Mas para isso você precisa estar dentro do contexto de uma requisição, como em uma view, por exemplo.

Os dados de um formulário são armazenados dentro da propriedade `form` do `request`, com exceção dos arquivos, o qual são atribuídos à  propriedade `files`

Exemplo de acesso aos dados do formulário

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
   # Print dos campos e valores passados pelo formulário
   print(request.form)

   # retorna os dados do formulário em formato JSON
   return jsonify(request.form)
```

O Python possui em sua biblioteca padrão o pacote [`pdb`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) para debug. Para adicionar o breakpoint apenas digite: `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`. A execução irá parar na linha em que você definiu esse comando.

Apesar do pacote `pdb` ser suficiente para muitos casos, é comum o uso do pacote [`ipdb`](https://github.com/gotcha/ipdb) para debug, por conta de algumas melhorias e facilidades que ele disponibiliza devido a integração com iPython, como: syntax highligh, auto-complete, melhor traceback, etc.

Para instalar o `ipdb`: `pip install ipdb`

Usando `ipdb` para debug do formulário do Flask

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
   # Print dos campos e valores passados pelo formulário
   print(request.form)

   # Execução da aplicação irá parar nesse ponto
   # Aqui você tem acesso a todas as váriaveis definidas no escopo.
   # É possível acessar, caso exista, o campo 'nome' passado pelo formulário, por meio da linha de comando
   # >>> request.form['nome']
   import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()

   # retorna os dados do formulário em formato JSON
   return jsonify(request.form)
```

Answer (score -1):

talvez assim:

```
print(object)
return
```

Comment: eu fiz conforme sua resposta e coloquei um testo no return apenas para testar, mas no browser aparece o texto do retorno, mas não aparece o debug. O print() deve imprimir algo no console do python, mas como a resposta é no browser, não sei se o print() tem saída para algum lugar, o que me parece que não.